# How to generate querydsl source code in eclipse kepler using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, querydsl

I want to learn Querydsl. so I went through this link

http://blog.mysema.com/2010/07/querying-hibernate-with-querydsl.html

I have used maven and eclipse kepler. Its genetering  the folder target/generated-sources but does not generating the java class i.e. QCustomer class.
I also googled for step by step tutorial but couldn't find.please help.I am beginner
Thanks

Comment: After lots of searching, my problem solved.I did some change in pom.xml and this step I followed    **bold**                     Right Click on project-Run as-Run Configuration-Maven Build-goals-apt:process

Comment: If had the solution put it in answers. It would be easy for others to identify :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work from console, i.e. calling `mvn compile`?

If not, do you have correctly annotated JPA entities in your artifact (are using Querydsl-JPA at all)?

It it does work from console, you may have to install the m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin (simply search the Eclipse marketplace).

Comment: Thanks,I followed your instructions but did not work.